# jQuery won't change DOM href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change href dynamically based on some language button selector to this image:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            var shownLang = Cookies.get('site_lang');
            if (shownLang == 'de') {
            $(".meranoiden").prop("href", "https://www.youtube.com/");
            // document.getElementById("meranoiden").setAttribute("href", "https://www.youtube.com/");
            console.log("enters here");
            console.log($('.meranoiden').prop('href'));
            }
        });
```

```html
<div class="meranologoen">
                    <div lang = "en" class="ui centered grid ">
                        <a class ="meranoiden"  lang = "en" href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"> <img class="merano-logo" src="assets/imgextra/logo/merano.png"> </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And for some unknown reason DOM won't replace my youtube link with the facebook one when if statement is called.

But in the console when I want to check my console.log I can see clearly that:

```
enters here 

https://www.youtube.com/
```

But when I inspect my picture it would still have the old facebook URL on the href.

I have tryed:

```
document.getElementById("meranoiden").setAttribute("href", "https://www.youtube.com/");
```

and

```
$(".meranoiden").attr("href", "https://www.youtube.com/");
```

Same behaviour, what could be the reason that href won't change ?

Comment: If you go to the trouble of making a code snippet, it should work to demonstrate the problem you're having.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `attr` instead of `prop`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var shownLang = Cookies.get('site_lang');
  if (shownLang == 'de') {
    $(".meranoiden").attr("href", "https://www.youtube.com/");
    console.log($('.meranoiden').attr('href'));
  }
});
```

Comment: Then maybe some problem with `Cookies.get`, because the jQuery code is correct

Answer (score 1):

Please check your code :

1. first check your Cookies.get() function.
2. Check your conditional(if) statement

Because i removed conditional(if) statement Your code is correct and work perfectly. so please check carefully and try again.